# Magnet loop to show in slideshow flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to make a loop to show images in a slideshow in flask, but I want to take the images that put the name of the image, I am trying with glob but this gives the following error:`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

python code

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
import glob
import os.path


app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():

    ruta_imagenes = glob(os.path.join(app.static_folder, "img"))
    render_template('index.html',ruta_imagenes=ruta_imagenes ) 





if __name__ == ('__main__'):
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for _, ruta in enumerate(rutas_imagenes)  %}
    <div class="carousel-item ">
            {% if _ == 0 %}active{% endif %}
        <img src="{{ ruta }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you need to pass the images into the template?

Comment: If I need to pass the images to the template, but even if I add this:render_template('index.html',ruta_imagenes=ruta_imagenes), it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the full python code for this minimal example.

Comment: Ready edit the question but in reality there is not much code comment this project recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing `glob` and then just calling it. But `glob` is a module.

What you want is either

```
import glob
glob.glob(os.path.join(app.static_folder, "img"))
```

or

```
from glob import glob
glob(os.path.join(app.static_folder, "img"))
```

Comment: Now I throw this error:
`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'enumerate' is undefined`

Comment: That's a separate issue. You might want to look into `loop.index`. If you think that this question is solved, can you mark it so. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures

Comment: Thank you I will continue investigating

Answer (score 1):

As @blueteeth mentioned you are importing glob module, which is not callable. You probably meant `glob.glob()` - a function, inside the glob module.

However, even then, `glob` is probably not what you are looking for. If you want to get a list of images you need to read files in the directory with something like:

```
ruta_imagenes = []
for root, dir, file in os.walk(path):
    ruta_imagenes.append(file)
```

And, of course, don't forget to pass these images to your template